# Reliable way to check for mobile in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile

I'm building a site in ASP.NET MVC/C#. I base most of my controllers off of a base controller. In that base controller I handle quite a few common tasks every controller needs to do.

One thing I want to add is a check for mobile browser. I've found some recommendations around SO, but they seem to be outdated.

What's a reliable way to check for mobile browser in C# (ASP.NET MVC)? (note: I already use stylesheet media queries for a responsive UI, but I need a way to detect mobile browser server side)

Comment: Is `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` reliable?

Comment: I think some one already asked that question:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233090/how-do-i-detect-a-mobile-browser-in-a-net-mvc3-application you can check this.

Comment: See my tutorial ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Comment: Thanks Rick, reading it over now.

Answer (score 4):

Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice  I'm using MVC4 not sure if this will work with regular request object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting blog article on Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice: http://dbarrowstechblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/requestbrowserismobiledevice.html It seems like there may be some limitations to this approach.

Overall, it's important to understand the considerable differences between what's called a "mobile device". It can be anything from a very primitive, almost text only, browser on an older phone to an iPhone or Android smartphone to a full featured experience on an iPad or Android tablet.

Tablet and advanced smartphone users hate dumbed down sites and hate sites that interfere with basic functionality like pinch-zoom. They like app'ed sites, when they work well, and sites that are optimized for performance but that are not stripped down to the bare bones.