# ASP.NET MVC3 detecting mobile device

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile

I have a ASP.Net mvc3 web application. I need to create a mobile version for this now.
I'm not able to decide which is this best way to detect a mobile device.

This whitepaper http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application gives few options. I'm not sure if I should go ahead with *51Degrees.mobi*.

Could someone who has implemented device detection, suggest a direction to proceed in. Pros and Cons of taking a particular route...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3514784/1184435) [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) question provides your answer regardless of `ASP.net MVC 3`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for server side device detection.

Comment: Then have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5233090/1184435) question.

Comment: The in built `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` does not include latest devices. 51Degrees.mobi is one way of doing, wanted to know if theres any drawbacks going this way or if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function IsMobileDevice() {
    var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
    return (platform.match(/iphone/) || platform.match(/ipod/) || platform.match(/ipad/));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your design Layout to support responsive design, check bootstrap or html5boilerplate, it's nothing related to server side.