# Resizing font on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a logo design below. On large screens it works ok but when I decrease the window size enough the right side of the logo gets cut off. I'd like for it to not be cut off and resize with the window instead. I could just use a media query here but I feel like I'm drastically missing something here. Any thoughts?

```css
#back {
  background: white;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#back .title {
  font-size: 7em;
  color: #074f66;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#back .title .highlight {
  color: #eebf3f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id='back'>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class='text-center'>
      <h2 class="title">my<span class="highlight">Logo</span></h2>
      <div class="bottom-spacer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--//col-->
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could detect the mobile and Increase the size manually if needed

[Mobile Device Detection in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086856/mobile-device-detection-in-asp-net)

[How do I detect a mobile browser in a .NET MVC3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233090/how-do-i-detect-a-mobile-browser-in-a-net-mvc3-application)

Answer (score 0):

Nop. You have only 2 options:

1) JS

2) Mediaqueries

Answer (score 0):

Just use a media query to change whatever rules at whichever breakpoint you want to see changes at.

See [MDN Using Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) & [@Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) along with Bootstraps default settings: [Bootstrap Media Queries](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).

**Example CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .title {
    font-size: 4em;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.title {
  font-size: 7em;
  color: #074f66;
  margin: 0;
}
.title .highlight {
  color: #eebf3f;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .title {
    font-size: 4em;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2 class="title text-center">my<span class="highlight">Logo</span></h2>
```